# NeoVim does not use ruby specified by rbenv on MacOS

Tags: ruby, rbenv, neovim

I have the following environment setup

- OS: macOS Catalina 10.15.7
- Zsh: 5.8
- Neovim: 0.4.4
- rbenv: 1.1.2

```
$ rbenv local
2.7.1

$ rbenv global
2.7.1

$ /usr/bin/ruby --version
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
```

`RBENV_VERSION` is not set. `rbenv-doctor` script also fine. Above all the facts, I assumed my rbenv setup is working.

When I am in neovim,

```
:echo has('ruby')
1

:ruby puts RUBY_VERSION
2.6.3
```

It **should have been** `2.7.1` but `2.6.3` (system ruby provided by macOS)

I have started with `nvim -u NORC` and still getting the same.

What should I check next to make NeoVim picks up rbenv specified ruby?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be reproduced in another (clean) account.

It was caused by messed up rbenv environment.

- rudimentary `neovim-ruby-host` remained in old ruby version (found out by `rbenv whence neovim-ruby-host` showing unused ruby version)
- rbenv shim (specifically gem) using system provided gem. (`rm`ed the shims and `rbenv rehash`ed)

rbenv doctor was not enough for the troubleshooting. The followings helped me find the cause

- `gem env` and `gem env home`: showed I was using system provided gem executable
- `rbenv rehash`: removed the staled shims and recreated them
- `rbenv which neovim-ruby-host`: showed actual path of neovim-ruby-host
- `rbenv whence neovim-ruby-host`: showed ruby versions providing the command (in my case incorrect one)